# Multiple Inheritance Columns in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord

I have an active record class (Animal) that has a type column and a gender column. Theoretically, I’d like to create multiple classes that inherit from Animal:

```
    class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
        self.inheritance_column = {‘type’, ‘gender’}
    end
```

Then add the inherited classes:

```
    class Dog < Animal
    end

    class Giraffe < Animal
    end

    class Male < Animal
    end
```

Is it possible to do this? I know that any column named ‘type’ is an inheritance column by default, but I’d like to define multiple columns to be the inheritance column. Not sure if it works, but I tried using an array above.

Comment: Unless I'm not seeing something, it doesn't really make sense to have multiple inheritance columns, since the `type` column is merely a discriminator. You could certain perform joins using those columns of course. Can you explain why you'd like to use multiple columns in STI?

Comment: Essentially, I'd like to have a class that includes (and deals only with) gender, but can include all types of animals. (I'm using gender & animal just as an example). So, for example a female class might include fields like pregnancy duration. However, all giraffes might include a field like neck-length. The data I'm working with is not that complex though, so I'd like to have all "animals" included in the same table, but have certain fields be null based on their gender or species type. Would a join be a better alternative?

Comment: Hmm ok I see. Yes, definitely a join would be the better alternative. If we think of it in the object-oriented way, an animal "has a" gender (ie composition). I can make a better post shortly to illustrate this, if you like (if no one else does it before me).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this today...

The answer seems to be **No** ... but also kind of yes.

What we *can* do is set `self.inheritance_column` to something else so it doesn't interfere, and then start building the things we need ourselves:

Let's say our classes look like so:

```rb
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = nil
end

class FemaleDog < Animal
end
class MaleDog < Animal
end

class FemaleGiraffe < Animal
end
class MaleGiraffe < Animal
end
```

If we have a formulaic way to combine two columns into the name, we can make a method like `auto_become` on our `Animal` class to help with instantiating the correct class:

```rb
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = nil

  self.auto_become
    becomes("#{gender}#{type}".constantize)
  end
end
```

Now whenever we find animals, we'll need to add a `auto_become` call:

```rb
# normal STI
Animal.where(:type => "Dog").all
=> (returns objects with class of "Dog")
# hacky STI
Animal.where(:type => "Dog", :gender => "Female").all
=> (returns objects with class of "Animal")
Animal.where(:type => "Dog", :gender => "Female").map(&:auto_become)
=> (returns objects with class of "Dog")
```

We will also need to fix the aspects where we would expect calls like `FemaleDog.all` to only query `where(:type => "Dog", :gender => "Female")` and `FemaleDog.new` to be initialized with `type = "Dog"` and `gender = "Female"`; both of these are broken by our hacky STI. A `default_scope` is one way to solve both (but be advised there's pitfalls with using `default_scope`, it is often not a good idea):

```rb
class FemaleDog < Animal
  default_scope -> { where(:type => "Dog", :gender => "Female") }
end
```

And I'm sure there's a lot of other things that would need to be fixed up. And to make it as magical as the built-in STI would require hooking into/overriding basically everything...